# Multi-dimensional arrays exercise: Introduce married couples to each other

Tags: array, kotlin

Following idea: There are three married couples and they have to be introduced another.

I have implemented this solution:

```
val couples = arrayOf(
    arrayOf("Michael", "Sandy"),
    arrayOf("Frank", "Claudia"),
    arrayOf("Andrew", "Michelle")
)

for (i in 0 until couples.size) {
    for (j in 0 until couples[0].size) {
        var currentPerson = couples[i][j]

        for (k in i + 1 until couples.size) {
           for (l in 0 until couples[0].size) {
               println("$currentPerson, this is ${couples[k][l]}.")
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

Results in:

```
Michael, this is Frank.
Michael, this is Claudia.
Michael, this is Andrew.
Michael, this is Michelle.
Sandy, this is Frank.
Sandy, this is Claudia.
Sandy, this is Andrew.
Sandy, this is Michelle.
Frank, this is Andrew.
Frank, this is Michelle.
Claudia, this is Andrew.
Claudia, this is Michelle.
```

So I guess it's formally correct. But using that many loops isn't great.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of loops? Or is there a completely different approach to solve the problem?

Comment: The data structures you've used seem a bit odd. Unless the names or couples will change at some point, it'd probably be best to use `listOf` to hold the list of couples, and to use a `Pair` for each couple. In case some of the couples get divorced, die, or become polygamous, you could perhaps use mutable lists for both the outer and inner lists. I also don't see a need to assign to `currentPerson` (and it can be a `val` instead of a `var` anyway).

Comment: It appears that each couple only has two people (since couples only consist of two people), so you can drop the second and fourth loops and just use `0` and `1` directly, unless you are planning for single people or more than two people as I've suggested above. I don't think you can do much else regarding the loops - the time complexity of this is going to be pretty high, but as long as you don't have too many couples to introduce to each other, it's probably fine.

Comment: @user I wish I could flag your comments with "Not a comment, it's an answer". I think you should post these things in an answer :)

Comment: @SimonForsberg I'll do so next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiency-wise, I don't think you can do any improvements. At least none that I can think of. The four loops will have to be there in some way or another, but can of course be abstracted behind functions so that it doesn't give you so many levels of nesting.

Things that can be improved however, is typing and extensibility.

Algorithmitically speaking, your code is a more specific version of "There are X groups containing varying amount of people and they have to be introduced to another."

---

`data class PeopleGroup(val people: Collection<String>)`

Order doesn't really matter so I'm not specifying whether it's a `List`, or a `Set`, we could even generalize it to `Iterable<String>` but that's a bit overkill.

```
val groups: MutableSet<PeopleGroup> = mutableSetOf(
    PeopleGroup(listOf("Michael", "Sandy")),
    PeopleGroup(listOf("Frank", "Claudia")),
    PeopleGroup(listOf("Andrew", "Michelle"))
)
```

That gives us some better structure. Note: I made it mutable so that we can remove already visited groups.

Now, to remove visited groups we can use an `Iterator`. And to handle the people to introduce a person to, we can use `flatMap`.

```
val iterator = groups.iterator()
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    val group = iterator.next()
    iterator.remove()

    for (person in group.people) {
        for (other in groups.flatMap { it.people }) {
            println("$person, this is $other.")
        }
    }
}
```

There are still some ways to improve this code, but I will leave you with this for now.

Comment: You can directly use [`mutableSetOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-set-of.html) to avoid the extra `toMutableSet()` (I don't know if that's idiomatic or if it has disadvantages, though).

Comment: @user Good point, fixed